# Making an Angular 2 button component that brings the user to the top of a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular

My goal is to program a button that brings the user to the top of a webpage on click. I am applying this logic directly in the button angular component file, then including it into the webpage through nesting it under a main component. I think there is a timing issue for when I am wiring up the logic. I have included all relevant code snippets, if there is anything else I can provide to better help users answer this question please let me know.

HACK: I've found that wrapping the angular component logic in a System.import promise introduces proper timing in wiring up the button logic. Not sure why though :/. Notice the commented code in the "Button component TypeScript" as an example of this.

HTML snippet from index.html where the main component is defined

```
<!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script>
            System.config({
            packages: {        
              src: {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
              }
            }
          });
          System.import("src/development/app/main-component.js")
                .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- main component -->
        <main>Loading...</main>
        <!-- end main component -->

        <!-- javascript -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>           
        <script type="text/javascript" src="src/development/js/main.js"></script>
        <!-- end javascript -->

    </body>

    </html>
```

Main component TypeScript

```
import {bootstrap} from "angular2/platform/browser";
import {Component} from "angular2/core";

import {FloatingActionButtonComponent} from "./shared/floating-action-button/floating-action-button-component";

/**
 * Configuration for the main Angular Component
 * @Component 
 * @attribute {directives} defines a list of components, allowing angular to properly identify the component selector
 */
@Component({
    directives: [
        FloatingActionButtonComponent
        ],
    selector: "main",
    templateUrl: "./src/development/app/main-view.html"
})  

export class MainComponent { }

bootstrap(MainComponent);
```

Main component view HMTL

```
<div id="main-container">

    <!-- floating action button -->
    <floating-action-button></floating-action-button>
    <!-- end floating action button -->

</div>
```

Button component TypeScript

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core";

@Component({
    selector: "floating-action-button",
    templateUrl: "./src/development/app/shared/floating-action-button/floating-action-button-view.html"
})

export class FloatingActionButtonComponent {

    constructor() {

        //System.import("path/to/a/directory/file.js").then(() => {
            if (document.getElementById("to-top-button") !== null) {
                document.getElementById("to-top-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
                    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                    console.log("click");
                });
            }
        //});
    }
}
```

Button component HTML

```
<div class="to-top-button">
    <button id="to-top-button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <br>Top
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think it's a timing issue, wrap the call in a `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(() => window.scrollTo(0, 0), 1);
```

If this doesn't work wrap the whole constructor content.

Comment: I'll give it a try, is this the best practice for handling issues like this?

Comment: Yes, this way you give the browser and Angular some time to complete pending async work.

Comment: I can confirm this implementation works `setTimeout(() => {
            if (document.getElementById("to-top-button") !== null) {
                document.getElementById("to-top-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
                    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                    console.log("click");
                });
            }
        }, 1);`

Comment: Great! Thanks for the feedback.